# Implementing custom HTTP methods with HttpCore

Tags: java, http, extension-methods, apache-httpcomponents

I'm new to Java and am hoping for some direction with Apache HttpCore library.

I've written a simple server, and would like to implement a few custom HTTP methods. I've gone through the docs a few time but haven't been able to figure it out.

It looks like the 501 Not Implemented is raised in [HttpService.doService()](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpService.java.html), but overriding that method doesn't work. My request handler doesn't get called.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here's the gist of what I've got:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    HttpParams params; 
    HttpService httpService;
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);

    params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
    params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 8 * 1024);
    params.setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false);
    params.setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true);
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.ORIGIN_SERVER, "?");

    BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseDate());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseServer());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseContent());
    httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseConnControl());

    HttpRequestHandlerRegistry registry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();
    registry.register("*", new HttpRequestHandler() {
        public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
                HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            System.out.println(request.getRequestLine().toString());

        }
    });

    httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(), new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());
    httpService.setParams(params);
    httpService.setHandlerResolver(registry);

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
    conn.bind(socket, params);

    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpService.handleRequest(conn, context);
    socket.close();
    conn.shutdown();

    serverSocket.close();
```

Response:

```
# curl -X FOO -i http://127.0.0.1:8000
HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Connection: Close

FOO method not supported
```

Request line isn't written to System.out unless method is GET, POST, etc.

SOLUTION: I needed to implement a HttpRequestFactory.
e.g.:

```
    DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection() {
        @Override
        public DefaultHttpRequestFactory createHttpRequestFactory() {
            return new DefaultHttpRequestFactory() {
                @Override
                public HttpRequest newHttpRequest(final RequestLine requestline) {
                    return new BasicHttpRequest(requestline);
                }
                @Override
                public HttpRequest newHttpRequest(final String method, final String uri) {
                    return new BasicHttpRequest(method, uri);
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need to override doService(). You rather need to implement a handler for you method and make sure

```
    handler = this.handlerResolver.lookup(requestURI);
```

returns your handler. I take you did that, but for some reason your handler is not found. I bet you didn't register it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've got a handler registered in HttpRequestHandlerRegistry. All standard methods are handled by it, but if I send a non-standard http method (e.g. curl -X FOO http://localhost), it doesn't get called. HttpService.doService() isn't reached either.